# iOS CoreLocation - What info is available for nearby devices?

Tags: ios, facebook, core-location

I'm wondering if it's possible to create an app that can detect other iOS devices that are nearby and have location services turned on? If so, what information is available? (I imagine this is a security issue so information such as phone number would not be available.) Also, what about 3rd party apps? For example, if the nearby device has the Facebook app installed, would it be possible to view their Facebook name/profile? My goal is to create an app that can send some type of request or message to someone who is near you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve it with Core Location directly.

You can, for example, send user's location to some your server,and fetch info about nearby users from server.

But people should use your app for it...

Comment: Thanks. If this is the case, then my app would be useless unless millions of people downloaded it. Like Tinder - Tinder would be useless unless millions of people have it. So I wonder - how do you get millions of people to download a useless app?

Comment: @user3925803 This is a very good question... A thousands of dollars were put in the marketing to achieve this ;-)